# Setting value to default in a django for loop

Tags: python, html, django

I've been stuck on a rather simple issue, where i'm trying to either set a value on a variable in a for loop, or setting the default data to N/a.

I set up a datatable that gathers lots of data, but i need to return 2 of the variables to N/a if not found in the for loop.

In the code example below, you can see a generic example of what i've tried.
In the 2 for loops i'm trying to set a global var, that i can than access outside of the for loop.

I've done some reading and i just can't figure out the smartest way of doing this.

Hence me asking the question here.

Please do ask if you need additional information.

```
                {% for vlan, macs in info.vlans.items %}
                {% for mac in macs %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor%}
            
            {% if vlan %}
            <td>{{vlan}}</td>
            {% else %}
            <td>N/a</td>
            {% endif %}

            {% if mac %}
            <td>{{mac}}</td>
            {% else %}
            <td>N/a</td>
            {% endif %}
```

I did also try to set the values within the for loop, but it won't work for the ones that do not have a mac or vlan assigned, as it does not set the default of N/a.

```
                {% for vlan, macs in info.vlans.items %}
            {% if vlan %}
            <td>{{vlan}}</td>
            {% else %}
            <td>N/a</td>
            {% endif %}
                {% for mac in macs %}
            {% if mac %}
            <td>{{mac}}</td>
            {% else %}
            <td>N/a</td>
            {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare it with None, that should help:

```
{% if mac is None %}
    <td>N/a</td>
{% else %}
    <td>{{mac}}</td>
{% endif %}
```

also you can try built-in default_is_none filter:

```
{{ mac|default_if_none:"N/a" }}
```

Comment: I've also tried a similar way of doing this, however if placed outside the for loop it does not return data, is there a way i can define a variable in the for loop, then assigning that outside of it?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to set a variable in django template, that's against their philosophy https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/language/#the-django-template-language

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by just seperating it.

Instead of what i tried to do before, i kind of simplyfied it.
It's not the cleanest type of code, but for now this works.

```html
                {% for switch, port in result.items %}
                {% for interface, info in port.items %}
                {% for vlan, macs in info.vlans.items %}
                {% for mac in macs %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{info.outlet}}</td>
                    <td>{{info.ruimte}}</td>
                    <td>{{switch}}</td>
                    <td>{{interface}}</td>
                    <td>{{ vlan|default_if_none:"N/a" }}</td>
                    <td>{{ mac|default_if_none:"N/a" }}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor%}
                {% endfor%}
                {% endfor%}

                {% for switch, port in result.items %}
                {% for interface, info in port.items %}
                <tr>
                <td>{{info.outlet}}</td>
                <td>{{info.ruimte}}</td>
                <td>{{switch}}</td>
                <td>{{interface}}</td>
                <td>N/a</td>
                <td>N/a</td>
```

I'd like to thank you for helping me out nevertheless, i never knew u couldn't set/get variables in django.